# How to "unwrap" Panel from a list of strings?

Tags: list-manipulation, formatting

I'm working with existing code that wraps a list in Panels. When I'm done with the portion needing Panel, how do I get just the list of strings back? Thank you!

```
Panel /@ Table[RandomWord[], 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
panels = Panel /@ Table[RandomWord[], 10]
```

[image]

You can use

```
Sequence @@@ panels (* or *)

# & @@@ panels (* or *)

ReplaceAll[Panel -> (# &)] @ panels

ReplaceAll[Panel -> Identity] @ panels
```

to get

[image]